# SearchHits in ElasticSearch contain no fields using Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am running this code to return matches

```
    public ArrayList<InnerText> suggest(String text, boolean isPersonal){

            TransportClient transportClient = new TransportClient();
            Client ESclient = transportClient.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("localhost", 9300));
            OrientGraph graph = new OrientGraph(ConnectionStrings.dbConnection);
            Map<String, Object> template_params = new HashMap<>();
            template_params.put("innerText", text);
            SearchResponse response = ESclient.prepareSearch()
                    .setTemplateName("innerText_match")
                    .setTemplateType(ScriptService.ScriptType.FILE)
                    .setTemplateParams(template_params)
                    .execute()
                    .actionGet();
            int index = 0;
            ArrayList<InnerText> list = new ArrayList<InnerText>();
            for (SearchHit hit : response.getHits()) {

                //String uuid = hit.field(InnerTextProps.uuid).toString();
                //InnerText innerText = vertexToInnerText(graph.getVertexByKey("InnerText.uuid",uuid),false);
                //list.add(null);
                //hit fields map is  org.elasticsearch.util.collect.EmptyImmutableMap
            }
            return list; 
    }
```

and I am getting hits back but the fields map for each of the SearchHits is empty (org.elasticsearch.util.collect.EmptyImmutableMap).Hits have correct id and type  though.  When using Sense plugin I see that things are stored and retrieved properly with the same query. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I am facing the same issue? Were you able to fix it?

Comment: No I haven't so what I did was to get the id and hit the database again :/

Comment: Have you found some solution in the mean time? I have the same issue (with 2.1.1) and I can see that `hit.getSourceAsString()` returns the complete content of the hit - so the data is returned.

Comment: No unfortunately I was refactoring my code in general and I didn't look into that part.. I am still doing the hacky id lookup :(. Please upvote so others can see it ..

Answer (score 5):

After some exploration of the different methods, I have found that:

- `SearchHit.sourceAsMap()` will give you access to the data if no specific fields were requested
- `SearchHit.getFields()` will give you access to the specific fields that were requested in your query using `SearchResponse.addFieldDataField( String )`

When the entire source is requested (as is the default) the `Map` object will contain either `String` values or subsequent `Map` values:

```
Map<String,Object> contents = hit.sourceAsMap();
for ( String name : contents.keySet() )
{
    Object value = contents.get(name);
    System.out.println( "Hit field: "+name+ " object: "+value.getClass().getName() );
    if ( contents.get(name) instanceof java.util.HashMap )
    {
        // Handle map object
    }
    else
    {
        // Handle string value
    }
}
```

Obviously when you request specific fields you can handle those using the `SearchHit` and `SearchHitField` APIs which are easier IMHO.

**EDIT**

After some more exploration, retrieving the values from the `SearchHitField` object is not so easy after all:

```
        Map<String,SearchHitField> fields = hit.getFields();
        System.out.println( "Hit fields: "+fields.size() );
        for ( SearchHitField field : fields.values() )
        {
            System.out.println( " Hit field: "+field.getName() );
            System.out.println( " Value: "+field.getValue() );
        }
```

Will yield only `null` for the values in my case. To be continued...

**EDIT2: Final Solutions**

*First*, the `addFieldDataField()` method only works if you specify *raw* fields to retrieve. Using analyzed fields will result in the error *"Field data loading is forbidden on `<fieldname>`"*.

*Secondly* when you retrieve fields using `addField()`, **always specify *leaf* fields** or the query will fail.

- Use `SearchResponse.addFieldDataField( <fieldname>.raw )`
- Use `SearchResponse.addField( <leaffieldname> )`

Now you can retrieve that field's content using `SearchHitField.getValue()`. 
Good luck.